# How can I define a function that set multiple variables without returning any value?

Tags: r, function, set, return

I have a function like below which takes a value and make an assignment to multiple variables. I want to be able to use those variables after I call this function once.

```
testfunction <- function(a) {
x <- a * a
y <- a + a
z <- a ^ a
}
testfunction(5)

> print(x)
Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found

> print(y)
Error in print(y) : object 'y' not found

> print(z)
Error in print(z) : object 'z' not found
```

any way to do that?

Comment: Store them all in a `list` and return `list(x,y,z)` then you can do `testfunction(a)$x` etc.

Comment: Why do you need to assign , you can return them in a list instead? `testfunction <- function(a) {
  list(x = a*a, y = a+a,z = a^a)
}` ?

Comment: If x,y,z are supposed to be global variables, you can use `x<<- a*a`. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html for further details

Comment: @Rohit Please don't promote bad practice. Especially not to newbies.

Comment: actually i tried to simplify with this example. my function creates multiple vectors with different sizes and and number of vector depends on the input of the function. So I may update the question as, how can I return multiple vectors with different sizes?